# How do I create a simple CSS animation while my div is in a column?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So let's say I have 3 images, each inside a div, in a 3 column setup as such.

```
<style>
#container {
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 40px;
}

.bit {
height: 400px;
background-image: url("https://www.whatever.com");
}
</style>


<div id="container">

<div class='bit' id="a"></div>
<div class='bit' id="b"></div>
<div class='bit' id="c"></div>

</div>
```

I want to have all of the divs sort of fly down from the top of the page when it's loaded. I am pretty new to the world of CSS animations, and I wrote the animations like this in the CSS file:

```
<style>
#a {
    position:relative;
    top: -500px;
    left: -200px;
    animation: slide 1.5s both;
}

#b {
    position: relative;
    top: -500px;
    animation: slide 1.5s both;
}

#c {
    position:relative;
    top: -500px;
    left: -200px;
    animation: slide 1.5s both;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0%{}
    100%{top: 0px}
    100%{left: 0px}
    100%{right: 0px}
}
</style>
```

When I load the page, the website interprets `top:500px` as go into the other column, which makes sense, but it's really annoying and doesn't make my animation go off the page at all. Just to be clear, #a works because it's in the first column. How can I make all three divs animate properly without leaking over to the next column?

Ideally, this wouldn't involve Javascript/JQuery at all, but if it's totally necessary then that's fine.